# How to force reload the tableview?Tableview accessory buttons and Tableview cell names are not changing the colour

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have changed the colour of `UITableViewCell` labels and did `reload` tableview

```
[m_cEntityView reloadData];

[m_cEntityView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.m_cSelectdPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

But it is taking so much time to reload `UITableView`, sometimes it is not showing the `accessory button` and it is in iPad `Rootview controller`. Please help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: you also need to put condition in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, to change the color.

Comment: Programatically it is executing the reload table statement and hmmm we also have condition for setting the colour and condition for resetting the colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with following method you can update whole section in table, given code will update section 0

```
[tblViewPortfolio beginUpdates];
[tblViewPortfolio reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tblViewPortfolio endUpdates];
```

Comment: But if i do like this it is taking.More than 1 second to scroll the rootviewcontroller tableview again.for 1 second we are not able to interact with table